# Chained subscribe calls in Meteor React Native

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-native

I am building a react native app with meteor using the library [react-native-meteor](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor) I am encountering an issue were I need perform a number of calls one after another e.g. call signin -> subscribe -> subscribe

In practice it looks something like:

```
//Get a list of folders from my backend where I know
//a folder called "Mirror" lives
Meteor.subscribe('folders')

//get the id of the folder called "Mirror"
var mirrorFolder = Meteor.collection('folders').findOne({name: 'Mirror'})

//Using the id of the mirror folder I need to get a list of files
//within the mirror folder
Meteor.subscribe('files', mirrorFolder._id)

//Then get a list of all the files
var files = Meteor.collection('files').find()
```

However due to the subscribe calls not being ready after I call them obviously this isn't possible. Am I missing a simple method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a handle to each subscription e.g.

```
var foldersHandle = Meteor.subscribe('folders'); 

if (foldersHandle.ready()) { // do something }
```

The above won't work as is, I'm just showing you the mechanism for checking if a subscription is ready. You'll need to check the ready status inside a reactive computation. You can probably use `createContainer` from the `react-meteor-data` package to make your react components reactive. I haven't used it with react native though.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. I ended up using the ready variable within a `Trackr.autorun` from the library Trackr (which is a fork of meteors Tracker) Thanks for the help.